# How to combine 2 learning rate schedulers in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to follow [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html) pytorch's optim documentation on using `optimizer.param_groups` to group several learning rate schedulers, but it seems like it only works for the `LambdaLR` one.

If I have my model:

```
net = Model()
```

I naively tried to add the schedulers with:

```
learning_rate = 0.02
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)
net.optimizer = optimizer

scheduler1 = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR(net.optimizer, base_lr=1e-10, max_lr=1e-3, step_size_up=3000, mode="triangular2", cycle_momentum=False)
net.scheduler1 = scheduler1

scheduler2 = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CyclicLR(optimizer, base_lr=1e3, max_lr=1e-1, step_size_up=1000, mode="triangular2", cycle_momentum=False)
net.scheduler2 = scheduler2
```

I'm trying to use `scheduler1` to train one of my neural networks, and `scheduler2` is just used for its value. That is, at each epoch I'm using its value to plug in into some function:

```
for epoch in num_epochs:
    loss = 5 - optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"]
```

Note that that's just an example function.

The issue is that I think the model just takes the `scheduler2` as its scheduler. Since
`optimizer.param_groups[1]["lr"]` returned:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Update 1**
For clarification, I have a neural network inside my model `net`. I want this neural network to have 1 lr scheduler, `scheduler1`. I have a certain function inside my model `net`, that needs to take certain values at each epoch. The values that it needs to take resemble the values from `scheduler2`. Hence, I need to add both schedulers to my model, using the first for my neural network, and the second to my function (not relating to any model's parameters except for the epoch number).

Comment: Your tutorial link points to pytorch's optim documentation, not a tutorial. Can you update this please ? Also the `net.params` method does not exist for an `nn.Module`, can you add its implementation here ? The "loss" function you put here makes no use of your schedulers, can you elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve ? Finally, afaik the `param_groups` list length have nothing to do with schedulers. If you want more than 1 param_group, you have the `add_param_group` method

Comment: @trialNerror Fixed "tutorial" issue. Updated with clarification. Not sure what you mean by "adding implementation of `nn.Module`?

Comment: `net.params` is not a `nn.Module` method. So either it is a mistake and you meant `net.parameters()`, either you have implemented this custom method and it may beneficial to paste its code here since it typically defines the param_groups which are used by the optimizer (By the way, the link still points toward pytorch documentation)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you have a variable in your network and you would like to have it cycle through different values, like the `lr` does thanks to `CyclicLR` ? Do you need it to have a "similar" cycle or do you need it to have the same value as your learning rate at all times ?

Comment: Ahh my bad. My model has several learnable parameters so I had to combine these with the parameters from the NN into a list called `params`. I just fixed it. In regards to the link, it's the link I found that showed how to group several learning rate schedulers. And yes, you're right. I want my variable to cycle through values that are exactly like the `CyclicLR`. In regards to the values, I'm not entirely sure I understand. The only use for the second lr scheduler is just for it's values

Comment: @Penguin Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Ivan Yes! Haven't been able to solve this yet

Comment: So you are using `scheduler2` only to keep track of a particular value?

Comment: @Ivan yes, exactly that

Comment: Why not keep it stored somewhere else? Will you change its value through `scheduler2.step()`?